# Conflict between nag and babel spanish

Tags: incompatibility, babel, spanish, nag

The following code gives me loads of `Font csname csname T1/cmtt/m/sc/10endcsname not found` errors.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
Testing bla bla bla . . .
\end{document}
```

There seems to be a conflict between the `nag` package (specifically with the `l2tabu`  and/or `orthodox` options) and the `spanish` option of the `babel` package.

I've tried the `es-noquoting` and `es-noshorthand` options with no success.

Does anyone else have this problem? I'm using MacTeX 2012, but I get the same error with TexLive 2011 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `nag` package says

```
\renewcommand\thenag@c{\roman{nag@c}}
```

but unfortunately the Spanish module for `babel` redefines `\roman` in a non expandable way, in order to print roman numerals in small caps rather that lowercase.

The solution is to avoid the usage of `\roman`:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thenag@c{\romannumeral\c@nag@c}
\makeatother
```

or to dispense with `nag` altogether. I simply prefer to avoid the mistakes myself. :)

Comment: Or to add the option `es-lcroman` to the `spanish` module: `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}`. This, however, might not really be advisable since it re-activates lower case roman numerals which are forbidden (by the RAE) in Spanish.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What's wrong is to redefine `\@roman` in the first place; they should've patched `\frontmatter` in the book class and told users how to change roman numbers in other cases (say `\pagenumbering{scroman}`).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that sorted things out. So you don't find useful the `nag` package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's another way of solving the problem. Personally I don't care a bit about those RAE conventions (which are erratically changed every now and then). Saludos!

Comment: @egreg How could you debug this one? Were you aware of this bug?

Comment: @NVaughan It was clearly a problem of expanding some "forbidden" command in a `\csname...\endcsname` construction and with some tracing on the culprit was found in `\es@lcroman` that appeared during the expansion of `\roman`. So I looked for `\roman` in `nag` and found the issue.

Comment: @egreg So the fault is in the spanish module of `babel`? I mean---the incompability that arouse with `nag` can also arise with other package, right? If so, should I contact the author of the module (I believe he is Javier Besos) to report the problem?

Comment: @NVaughan It's my opinion. A class made by a friend of mine used to do the same (the author hates lowercase roman numbers), but for example the `\lipsum` package ceases to work (the same with Spanish babel, by the way). He finally decided to opt for a `\scroman` command.

Comment: @egreg I have just sent an email to Javier Bezos redirecting him here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the bug is in `nag`, because it uses `\thenag@n` inside a `\csname`, which in turn calls `\roman`, intended for the *visual* (ie, printed) representation of Roman numerals. Note also "internal" counters (`\@roman`, in this case) are not required to be fully expandable, and in fact `\alph` in spanish is not (to include the *ñ* after the *n*), like `\fnsymbol` in LaTeX itself. If you want Roman numerals at the low level, `\romannumeral\the` should be used, which is LaTeX does in lists. On the other hand, changing every instance of `\roman` in LaTeX (not only the `\frontmatter` page numbers) would be a mess. Anyway, spanish provides a very simple workaround.