# Conflict between stackengine and babel with spanish option

Tags: babel, incompatibility, stackengine

When pdfLaTeXing the MWE below I get a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error message. The compilation proceeds with no errors as soon as the `babel` package is not loaded with the `spanish` option (well, to be true, I've only tried with the `english` option, and it works alright). Any hints on how to solve this issue, or on a possible workaround, would be welcome.

Follows the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\Shortstack[c]{A N E}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I've just tried with the `es-noquoting` option and with the coupled commands `\deactivatequoting`-`\activatequoting`, as suggested in some posts about issues related to `spanish babel`, but to no avail. The problem remains the same.

Comment: An update to `stackengine` has been submitted to CTAN, based on Ulrike's answer.  It should propagate in the coming days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

stackengine uses the command `\roman` in a csname (which is simply not a good idea: `\roman` is for printing and not for the generation of command names) and this breaks as spanish redefines `\@roman`. As a workaround you can disable the redefinition but imho stackengine should be corrected.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\makeatletter
\let\ori@roman\@roman
\usepackage[spanish,]{babel}
\let\@roman\ori@roman


\begin{document}
\Shortstack[c]{A N E}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `\roman` should not be used, does the same admonition apply to `\romannumeral`?  Your answer is the first I've heard about this topic.  Are there any other pointers to this topic?

Comment: @{Ulrike Fischer, Steven B. Segletes}: That made it. I've resorted to using the `es-lcroman` option, though, which also solves the issue, as discussed on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64687/conflict-between-nag-and-babel-spanish?rq=1, and where further discussion can be found.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: `\romannumeral` is ok. And the same problem is with `\arabic`, e.g. here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32229/2388. But if you look a bit around you will find other similar discussion.